# Labeling only line vertices in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, line, vertices

I want to only put labels on the vertices of the polylines.  I can use the data defined features to place a label at specific points, but not at multiple specific points.

Is it possible to label only the polyline vertices in QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can extract the vertices to a new point layer, make the point layer transparent and label the points. Menu: Vector > Geometry Tools > Extract Nodes...